# How to show absence dates for employee (not found in log checkinout table)?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

```
DECLARE @Dateval1 AS date = '2022-05-01'
DECLARE @Dateval2 AS date = '2022-05-10'
DECLARE @empid AS integer = 11487

SELECT 
    USERINFO.BADGENUMBER AS Empid, 
    CASE 
        WHEN CHECKTYPE = 'I' THEN 'checkIn'
        WHEN CHECKTYPE = 'O' THEN 'checkOut'
        ELSE 'now'
    END AS 'type',
    CONVERT(varchar, CHECKTIME, 23) AS [Date],
    CONVERT(char(10), CHECKTIME, 108) AS [Time],
    DATENAME(WEEKDAY, CHECKTIME) AS [Day Name]
FROM            
    CHECKINOUT 
INNER JOIN
    USERINFO ON CHECKINOUT.USERID = USERINFO.USERID
WHERE 
    CHECKTIME BETWEEN @Dateval1 AND DATEADD(day, 1, @Dateval2)
    AND BADGENUMBER = @Empid
```

The output is :

```
Empid   type      Date          Time        Day Name
-----------------------------------------------------
11487   checkIn   2022-05-09    08:55:16    Monday
11487   checkOut  2022-05-09    15:23:07    Monday
11487   checkIn   2022-05-10    08:51:43    Tuesday
11487   checkOut  2022-05-10    15:22:24    Tuesday
```

I need to show date between above dates in the SQL query and set it absence?

I need to show the data like this:

```
Empid   type      Date        Time        Day Name
----------------------------------------------------
11487   absence   2022-05-08  08:55:16    Saturday
11487   checkIn   2022-05-09  08:55:16    Monday
11487   checkOut  2022-05-09  15:23:07    Monday
11487   checkIn   2022-05-10  08:51:43    Tuesday
11487   checkOut  2022-05-10  15:22:24    Tuesday
```

Comment: LEFT JOIN your result set from the query with a **calendar** table that contains all the dates in the time period you're looking at - those dates that aren't in your result set will have `NULL` for their query columns - which you can replace with `absence` in your output

Comment: Are you going to further query the result? It sounds more like a post-processing need than a SQL query to me. It would be simpler to do it with a for loop over the query result.